# How to create a list of Multiple Sequence Alignment objects in Biopython?

Tags: biopython

Probably simple question, but I am having trouble creating a simple list of MultipleSeqAlignment objects.

```
from Bio import AlignIO
import Bio.Align

#Read multi-aligned fasta file
alignment = AlignIO.read(sys.argv[1], "fasta")

#some testing values
first_POI = 10 #base position
major = "a" #major allele
minor = "g" #minor allele

#create lists of sequence ids that are major or minor allele
align_major = Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment([])
align_minor = Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment([])

for record in alignment:
    if (record.seq[first_POI] == major):
        #compile the sequences that have major allele
        align_major = align_major + record
    elif (record.seq[first_POI] == minor):
        #compile sequences with minor allele
        align_minor = align_minor + record
```

I get this error:

```
  File "FindHaplotypes.py", line 53, in <module>
    align_major=align_major+record
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\Bio\Align\__init__.py", line 385, in __add__
    raise NotImplementedError
```

So I am somewhat confused and I can already imagine that the `MultipleSeqAlignment` from `Bio.Align` is probably not the same type of object that is stored for `Bio.AlignIO`. I assumed since they both dealt with MSAs they would be the same. I know for my `AlignIO` objects I can add them together like strings, but problem is I do not know how to initialize an empty `AlignIO` object to add them together in the above fashion. Previously I had to do it in an ugly fashion by setting the first record to the new variable and then entering the for loop to add to it.

Comment: Note Bio.AlignIO does return the Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment objects.

Comment: So is there a way to initialize an empty `AlignIO` object to add `AlignIO.read` objects to? Or is the way I am doing the correct way? I think in my original code I was importing so many different libraries for `Bio.Align`, `Bio.Seq` and `AlignIO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: `NotImplementedError`. The Biopython implementation of `__add__` in `MultipleSeqAlignment` requires that the two objects are instances of `MultipleSeqAlignment`. Additions involving other objects are not implemented.

You should use the method `append()` of your msa:

```
for record in alignment:
    if (record.seq[first_POI]==major):
        #compile the sequences that have major allele
        align_major.append(record)
    elif (record.seq[first_POI]==minor):
        #compile sequences with minor allele
        align_minor.append(record)
```

This needs `record` to be a `SeqRecord`, with the same `Alphabet` of `align_mayor` and `align_minor` and the same lenght.

Comment: omg that worked! Thank you!

I don't think I fully understand your explanation. I understand that `__add__` is not a method in `MultipleSeqAlignment`, but how was I able to add a `AlignIO` object to a `MultipleSeqAlignment` object? Is it because they both use `SeqRecord`? I tried looking at the source code but I am still too much of a novice to figure this out.

Comment: `__add__` IS a method of `MultipleSeqAlignment`. It happens to accept only `MultipleSeqAlignment` objects (like the one that returns `AlignIO`), NOT `SeqRecords`.

Comment: Use help(alignment) for more details - or read it online at http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment-class.html